# x-axis is not plotting properly in c3.js when there is interval data which is in DST time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to plot a graph with c3.js library having x-axis in interval time.
We're formulating these interval according to the date range picker So if we choose the dates 2016-03-13 00:00 to 2016-03-13 04:00 then we are adding 15 minutes to the start date until it remains less or equal to the end date

The data point I am taking is as follows:
["x", "2016-03-13 00:00", "2016-03-13 00:15", "2016-03-13 00:30", "2016-03-13 00:45", "2016-03-13 01:00", "2016-03-13 01:15", "2016-03-13 01:30", "2016-03-13 01:45", "2016-03-13 02:00", "2016-03-13 02:15", "2016-03-13 02:30", "2016-03-13 02:45", "2016-03-13 03:00", "2016-03-13 03:15", "2016-03-13 03:30", "2016-03-13 03:45", "2016-03-13 04:00"]
These points are working fine when there is no DST happening in the timezone. But when DST is applicable the point between 2 am to 3 am is missing in the graph due to this the scale is 23 hours.
We need all the point to draw in the graph regardless where the DST is applicable or not.
The following code we are using but it is not working

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
         xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x'
        columns: [
            ["x", "2016-03-13 00:00", "2016-03-13 00:15", "2016-03-13 00:30", "2016-03-13 00:45", "2016-03-13 01:00", "2016-03-13 01:15", "2016-03-13 01:30", "2016-03-13 01:45", "2016-03-13 02:00", "2016-03-13 02:15", "2016-03-13 02:30", "2016-03-13 02:45", "2016-03-13 03:00", "2016-03-13 03:15", "2016-03-13 03:30", "2016-03-13 03:45", "2016-03-13 04:00"],//            ['x', '20130101', '20130102', '20130103', '20130104', '20130105', '20130106'],
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250,30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250.30, 200, 100, 400, 150]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',

             fit: true,
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of settings that switch between local and utc time, one for the data and one for the axis, though the data one is not officially exposed yet and has to be done via c3's internal property

```
c3.chart.internal.fn.additionalConfig.data_xLocaltime = false;

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
         xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x'
        columns: [
            ["x", "2016-03-13 00:00", "2016-03-13 00:15", "2016-03-13 00:30", "2016-03-13 00:45", "2016-03-13 01:00", "2016-03-13 01:15", "2016-03-13 01:30", "2016-03-13 01:45", "2016-03-13 02:00", "2016-03-13 02:15", "2016-03-13 02:30", "2016-03-13 02:45", "2016-03-13 03:00", "2016-03-13 03:15", "2016-03-13 03:30", "2016-03-13 03:45", "2016-03-13 04:00"],
            /*["x", "2016-03-27 00:00", "2016-03-27 00:15", "2016-03-27 00:30", "2016-03-27 00:45", "2016-03-27 01:00", "2016-03-27 01:15", "2016-03-27 01:30", "2016-03-27 01:45", "2016-03-27 02:00", "2016-03-27 02:15", "2016-03-27 02:30", "2016-03-27 02:45", "2016-03-27 03:00", "2016-03-27 03:15", "2016-03-27 03:30", "2016-03-27 03:45", "2016-03-27 04:00"],*/
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250,30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250.30, 200, 100, 400, 150]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',

             fit: true,
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            },
            localtime: false,
        }
    }
});
```

(the 2016-03-27 data I used to test in the uk locale as that's when the daylight hour change happens here)

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this.  I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to get C3 to parse dates in the data as UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Try using date strings with the timezone offset.

```
var dateFormatter=d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%Z");
columns[0].forEach(function(d,idx,theArray){
    if(d!='x'){
        theArray[idx] = dateFormatter(new Date(d));
    }
});
```

Comment: `["x", "2016-03-13 00:00-0500", "2016-03-13 00:15-0500", "2016-03-13 00:30-0500", "2016-03-13 00:45-0500", "2016-03-13 01:00-0500", "2016-03-13 01:15-0500", "2016-03-13 01:30-0500", "2016-03-13 01:45-0500", "2016-03-13 03:00-0400", "2016-03-13 03:15-0400", "2016-03-13 03:30-0400", "2016-03-13 03:45-0400", "2016-03-13 03:00-0400", "2016-03-13 03:15-0400", "2016-03-13 03:30-0400", "2016-03-13 03:45-0400", "2016-03-13 04:00-0400"]` 
I am getting this array with the above patch.
Here 3 am interval is repeating twice but we need 2 am interval.